# What would be another term for a person in their 50s and 60s other than "boomer" or "Gen-Xer"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, politeness, gender-politics

What would be another term for a person in their 50s and 60s other than "boomer" or "Gen-Xer"? People in their late 50s are technically baby-boomers, but "boomers" doesn't quite fit. People in their early 50s are "Gen-Xers" but that name has lost its meaning.
What could be some good names for people that are older, in general?
Elderly and even senior-citizen are just awful names!
What are some positive and non-ageist names for these people?

Comment: Semi-centurians!

Comment: well I would certainly prefer Elderly and Senior-citizen to be called a "boomers" or "Gen-Xers" any day of the week.  But I would prefer to be called In my  60s. At least everyone knows what the meaning is.

Comment: baby boomers and gen-xers are not the same generation **at all**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Older than Middle-Aged, Younger than Elderly](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292686/older-than-middle-aged-younger-than-elderly)

Comment: Not *at all*? What magic happened at exactly 12 am January 1, 1965?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for another term for boomers or a term for people ages 50-60? These two categories overlap now, but they won’t as time goes on.

If the latter, [neutral (albeit obscure) terms](https://theelderlies.wordpress.com/2006/10/02/age-by-decade/) are:

> - **Quinquagenarian**: Someone in his or her fifties.
> - **Sexagenarian**: Someone in his or her sixties.

(Of the -genarian words, I have only seen *octogenarian* used “in the wild”.)

Comment: That reminds me of, “Yeah, that guy is an admitted sexagenarian who has been seen perambulating small children- even his own grandson.”

Comment: Thank you! That joke made this whole question worthwhile!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't going to be a term for every arbitrary range of ages, but a conventional division of a person's life would identify people between youth and agedness as ***middle-aged***. As [Collins COBUILD](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/middle-age) defines it,

> **Middle age** is the period in your life when you are no longer young but have not yet become old. Middle age is usually considered to take place between the ages of 40 and 60.

A similar term is ***[midlife](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/midlife)***, as in the Collins English Dictionary:

> *adjective*
>   1. of or relating to middle age; of the period of life between about 40 and 60
>
> *noun*
>   2. the period of life between about 40 and 60

These are not set figures. Some would define middle age beginning as early as 35, others might postpone it to 50; the AARP will take your dues starting at 55 while others, citing healthier living, would push seniorhood to 70 nowadays.

There is a dissonance between your stated desire to avoid ageism and your declaration that *elderly* and *senior-citizen* are "just awful" terms. If you think that any term, however clinical, which labels someone as other than young is unacceptable, then *middle-aged* and *at midlife* will not be suitable, either. Reaching midlife is associated with the *[midlife crisis](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/conditions/midlife)*, but like *elderly* or *senior*, these are descriptive terms, not slurs, and less patronizing than *matured* or *golden-aged* and so on and so forth.

Comment: Touché. It is ageist of me to say those terms are unpleasant.

Answer (score -1):

Such people are sometimes said to be **mature**, given by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/mature) as

> **mature**
>   ADJECTIVE
>
> **1.3** Used euphemistically to describe someone middle-aged or old.
>   *Miss Walker was a mature lady when she married*

The term is more complimentary than ageist and can be applied to a wide age range.

Comment: you get my up vote I like mature it sounds good. However I have my worries that being associated with a piece of Cheddar is not meant as a complement.

Comment: Yes, but though aging is compulsory maturing is optional :-)

Comment: Nonetheless, "mature" *is* a term used to mean somone who isn't young, although it has other meanings too.

Answer (score -1):

The expression ***[third age](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/the-third-age)*** is generally used within positive contexts such as sports, traveling etc.

> the period of time that is after middle age and before old age, when people are still active. (MacMillan Dictionary)

[Leisure Activity in the Third Age](http://healthcare-communications.imedpub.com/leisure-activity-in-the-third-age.php?aid=21706)

> Age; Recreation; Leisure activity; Health and quality of life

Comment: @Brad - the Third Age 
***old age, esp when viewed as an opportunity for travel, further education, etc*** Collins Dictionary. Rubbish your comment, though.

Comment: wow what happens with the kids then, they missed the baby, toddler, child and teenager stages and go straight into young age? presumably that is  1st age:  then middle age presumably second age and then old age? third age?

Comment: I stand corrected, well researched, It is very obscure it is not in MW or Cambridge, amusingly it is depicted by Collins as British but Cambridge is unaware of it. Anyway that is something else I learnt today. Does not make me feel any younger though, now I am in my third age.

Comment: This sounds French: le troisième age,for pete's sake.