# Euphemism for "old" (person)

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, euphemisms

Almost every language has polite ways to say that someone is old and that someone is getting ones. Are they usual in English? If so, which is the most usual euphemism in English to express these two ideas nowadays? Below are the ones I am familiar with:

to be old

- He is advanced in age.
- He is advanced in years.
- He is of advanced age. (less usual)

to get old

- Aunt Betty is getting along in years

Comment: Please see this recent similar question: [What would be another term for a person in their 50s and 60s other than “boomer” or “Gen-Xer”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/509607/what-would-be-another-term-for-a-person-in-their-50s-and-60s-other-than-boomer)

Comment: He has got his [bus pass](https://www.gov.uk/apply-for-elderly-person-bus-pass) (informal UK).

Comment: Erm..."senior citizen"?

Comment: Are you looking for a specific phrase you have heard before? If so, can you remember any details at all (if a particular word stands out, what situation it was used in, whether it was humourous, how old the person was that said it, which country it was said in, etc)?

Comment: The most common adjective would probably be "elderly."  It's not really a euphemism, though.  It's just a polite way of saying it in formal conversation.

Comment: What does "old" mean to you? When I was only in my 30s students considered me old. Gandalf was OLD, but was referred to as an "elderly chap" at the Inn of the Prancing Pony.

Comment: Boomers and Gen-Xers are entirely different.  Different generation, by definition.  Because this is a generational designation, "boomers" (e.g.) is not a word that has an age associated with it, i.e., Gen-Xers do not become boomers as they age.

Comment: It all depends on the context, and on the person being described. If you want to say " Despite being [old] he ran the London marathon in record time", that is one thing. But if you want to say "Because he is [old] you cannot expect him to be as quick as he once was" a different euphemism is needed. Bizarrely, in the second case 'older' is often used. (Older than what?). You have to tailor your euphemism to the specific circumstances. BTW the next person who calls me 'old' gets a black eye. I am over 70.

Comment: @marcellothearcane I am not looking for a specific phrase, I just want some usual options

Comment: @Cascabel At what age someone gets physically old is indeed relative, but IMHO that is outside the scope of this discussion. We can think about a 100 year old man to avoid any controversy.

Comment: For  a good jaja, see this clip  from Mel Brooks [the 2000-year-old man](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XOTKDgrdvdg)  "ah...Jesus. Good Jewish boy."

Comment: Some people find *elderly* more offensive than *old*, I think because *elderly* can imply fragility or decline, whereas (depending on context) *old* may simply imply *not young*.

Comment: *"I am not looking for a specific phrase, I just want some usual options."* That's too broad a question for this site. If you're going to ask a question, you need to provide sufficient criteria that would let a *single* answer be reasonable. Just asking for a list of synonymous words and phrases (and in multiple contexts) is too general. (You could look up [*old* in a thesaurus](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/old) for that.)

Comment: @JasonBassford that link does not provide several expressions mentioned here so far (eg advanced in age, along in years). Also, it does not mention which expressions are the most usual.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Synonyms listed in thesauruses *are* the most usual—almost by definition. If they were highly unusual, they wouldn't be listed. If you're just asking *us* (random individuals on the internet) what's the most usual, that's primarily opinion-based, and not a good question either. Anything that's the equivalent of *give me a list of words* (even if it's one word per person) isn't a great question. You really need to provide context and criteria. Otherwise, we're just throwing darts at a dart board in the dark.

Comment: @JasonBassford OK then. I was under the impression that "advanced in age" was usual. Maybe I am mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

One such idiom is **along in years**:

> Definition: Someone who is old, growing old, or elderly.
>
> The idiomatic expression *along in years* refers to someone who is old or elderly.  Native English speakers use it as a euphemism to illustrate that someone is growing older.
>
> When used in this context, the verb *getting* often precedes the phrase.
> <sub>[Writing Explained](https://writingexplained.org/idiom-dictionary/along-in-years)</sub>

This idiom can be used to describe people or animals.

Answer (score 0):

(theoretically when a person is too old to work.  This used to be 60 for the U.K. state pension.  Years ago they were called ‘old age pensioners’.  That age is increasing towards 68.  But many retire earlier;  pilots and people in the armed forces, for example.  Roman soldiers in the empire served for 25 years.  So retirement would have been around 50 or so, and the Latin word for ‘old’ (senex) was for those too old to be soldiers.

The age at which people feel or seem old varies.  But I suggest that it begins when we (yes, I am old) when we start to realise there are more and more things we cannot do that we could do before.  These may be physical.  I used to be able to amuse my kids by fully exhaling and staying on the bottom of the pool and staying there.  Now I just float back up:  my body is less dense than it was.  Then there was when I couldn’t stand on my head any more or do a ‘spider’ though I was good at gymnastics at school..  and though I can still run down stairs and climb ladders and trees, I am much more cautious now, because I am aware that a fall is more likely to do serious damage that would be slower to heel.  Age may show up in other ways too:  a less efficient short term memory, for example.  But I should propose 60 as a sensible age after which old people could be said to be old:  perhaps 65.; certainly 70.

Comment: My question is about expressions used as euphemism for old (people). This answer is completely out of scope.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista But you haven't really described a scope. This is questioning what you judge *old* to be referring to. It's not even clear why you think *old* itself isn't polite, making something else a better choice. And, taking one example from this answer, why would *pensioner* not be a euphemism?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista. Yes, you are right.  I got so wrapped up in the use that there is no reason for the word ‘old’ to have derogatory connotations, that I forgot to include my actual answer.  It must be my age!  The reason for euphemism is, of course, ageism, in which it is assumed that old people are less capable of certain things, or are all a bit dotty.  There is a very good French euphemism:  ‘le troisième age’ (the third age.  There is even a ‘université du troisième age).  Trouble is, it has no corresponding g adjective.  [ continued].

Comment: @JasonBassford The trouble with euphemisms is that they do not work.  They paper over the cracks of prejudice, whether about sexual identity,  ethnic identity or age.  But in a short time the prejudice shows through, and the euphemism sounds condescending.  And they soon become an excuse for the prejudiced to inveigh against ‘political correctness’.  So the euphemism becomes not a changer of attitudes but a means to avoid the disapproval of others.  Old people are old.

Comment: @JasonBassford Sorry to disagree, but I have (IMHO clearly) defined the scope. The proof is that the other answer provides an alternative expression for "old". Also, IMHO "pensioner" is not related with my question. I think that nobody would say today "That man is a pensioner" with the main purpose of saying that he is old; instead, the age is only a consequence of the main fact. I'm not interested in terms which are not used nowadays. I have added it to the question to make it clear.